# Segue won't execute Swift

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, segue

I have a segue running form a Collection View (wrapped in a view controller)  in to a another view controller, how ever the function never gets called:

```
  func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  println(segue.identifier)
  println(sender)
  println("SEGUE SELECTED:  \(segue.identifier)")

  if(segue.identifier == "segueToDetailView") {
    let cell = sender as CollectionViewCell;
  }
}
```

Have placed a breakpoint at start of function but never reached.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: have you called `performSegueWithIdentifier` ?

Comment: I was working form a template where the prepareForSegue seemed to be called implicitly when a cell was selected in a CollectionView.

Comment: However when the CollectionView became a subview of a view controller nothing happened when image in cell was selected. So I added a button and called performSegueWithIdentfer and now segue is called but the app crashes when trying to get the indexPath let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForCell(cell)

Comment: so the segue is being performed, but `prepareForSegue` is not called?
Or the segue is not performed?

Comment: If the segue is made directly from the cell, that segue should be executed when you select the cell. If you have an image view in there, make sure you've set its userInteractionEnabled property to true, or the cell won't be selected when you touch the image. That's probably the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks the segue was not running from the cell, stupid newbie mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest not to create segue(s) from cell or any object(like button).
Create segue from one ViewController to OtherViewController with unique identifier.
And then call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` yourself using the identifier.

Comment: Why? It's perfectly fine to make segues from buttons or cells.

Comment: @rdelmar Right, but OP is having difficulty identifying the object which is triggering the segue. So I thought doing it manually will clear things.

Comment: Thanks, this helped show me that i was running the segue from wrong place on view controller, i.e. not the Cell