# Login form in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Can you guys help me please with some code? i have signup form in xcode 6.3 and i want that if the username and password is < 5 then cannot go further to next logged in view controller. Code here:

```
//
//  CustomSignupViewController.swift
//  CustomLogin
//
//  Created by PJ Vea on 3/11/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Vea Software. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class CustomSignupViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

var actInd : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.actInd.center = self.view.center
    self.actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(self.actInd)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func signUpAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var username = self.usernameField.text
    var password = self.passwordField.text
    var email = self.emailField.text

    if count(username) < 4 || count(password) < 5 {

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Username must be greater then 4 and Password must be greater then 5", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    }else if count (email) < 8 {

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Please enter a valid password.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()


    }else {

        self.actInd.startAnimating()

        var newUser = PFUser()
        newUser.username = username
        newUser.password = password
        newUser.email = email

        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in

            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if ((error) != nil) {

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            }else {

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Signed Up and Logged In", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            }

        })

    }

}
}
```

I will be very thankful for answer! :)

Comment: Can you post things you've tried so far...where you're getting stuck etc?

Comment: can you show me output for your username and password

Comment: I've made new view controller where is only logout button. But if i input under 5 symbols in username or password signup table then it goes further to the new made view controller where is logout button. I want that it shows error and dont go anywhere.

Comment: there is no output, it just segues to other view controller even if there is < 5 symbols

Comment: you can try like this if count(username) <= 4 || count(password) <=5

Comment: Have you setup you segue in storyboard? Then you have to `performSegueWithIdentifier` programmatically.

Comment: I don't need equal to 4 or 5. I need that it don't go further to logged in vc. I need that it gives me error that there is less than 4 - username, 5 - password

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have setup your segue in Storyboard, give the segue an identifier. (say , `yourID`)

Then invoke the following method.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourId", sender: self)
```

when you want to go to the next ViewController.

**EDIT**

call the method in last else.

```
}else {

    self.actInd.startAnimating()

    var newUser = PFUser()
    newUser.username = username
    newUser.password = password
    newUser.email = email

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourId", sender: self)
    newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in
```

Comment: Yes but i need it active only when in the sign up username symbols are > then 5 and password are > then 4.

Comment: It still dont make user and continues to new segue if its < 5 symbols.

Comment: It seems you have created segue from button. Setup the Segues from ViewController instead.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062765/segue-wont-execute-swift/29063658#29063658